# Brauer trees that are Hopf algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hopf-algebras

Let $T$ be a Brauer tree with associated Brauer tree algebra $KT$ for some field $K$.

> Question 1: For which Brauer trees does there exist a field $K$ such that $KT$ is a Hopf algebra (or more precisly, there exists a Hopf algebra structure such that $KT$ is a Hopf algebra with its natural algebra structure)?

> Question 2: For which $T$ is $KT$ Morita equivalent to a Hopf algebra for some field $K$?

For example $K[x]/(x^p)$ (a Brauer tree algebra for $T$ a line with two point and multiplicity $p-1$) is isomorphic to a Hopf algebra when $K$ has characteristic $p$.

Comment: $KT$ is a lousy notation for such a Brauer tree algebra - and you probably want "up to Morita equivalence". Also, it's not true that stars and lines are always realised by group algebras of finite groups - at least the determinant of the Cartan matrix would have to be a power of the characteristic.

Comment: @DaveBenson Thanks. You are right, there are two seperate question. One about Morita equivalence and one about isomorphic to a Hopf algebra.